# Remote Raspberry Pi from Notepad++: private key error?

Tags: remote, putty

I want to remote file from Raspberry Pi through Notepad++.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.dexterindustries.com/BrickPi/program-it/hints-and-tricks/).

Then, I've got the exactly error like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939684/notepad-nppftp-plugin-fails-to-connect-via-sftp).

What I still don't get  from the answer is the guy said that we need to us PuttyGen  for exporting the private key and then use it for Notepad++ but I'm not sure in this case I need to use PuttyGen in PC or in Raspberry Pi ? 
And if you have done it with Raspberry Pi,  could you summary your solution ?

Comment: Puttygen is done on the PC side.

Comment: @SteveRobillard so I just Generate the key (it tells me to move the mouse) and then Export the key to a .ppk file and then browse to it in *private key file* in *Authetication* of Notepad++ ? Is that right ?